# java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, server, build.gradle, socketexception

On my console:
my server is running fine with `gradle run`, but when I go into my website\trunk and try to run `gradlew appRun`, I get the following errors.

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed
```

I have checked my firewall settings, and also disabled it.  Unfortunately, it did not make a difference.

I also manually installed gradle, but I'm still getting this exception.   What do you think could be the problem?

Here's the full console output including the error:

From running **`gradlew appRun`:**

```
> C:\Users\IJ\website\trunk>**gradlew appRun**
:librideabike:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:librideabike:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:librideabike:classes UP-TO-DATE
:librideabike:jar UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInplaceWebAppClasses UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInplaceWebApp UP-TO-DATE
:appRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*** What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appRun'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed**

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.578 secs
```

This is from **`gradlew appRun --stacktrace`:**

```
> C:\Users\IJ\website\trunk>**gradlew appRun --stacktrace**
:librideabike:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:librideabike:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:librideabike:classes UP-TO-DATE
:librideabike:jar UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInplaceWebAppClasses UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInplaceWebAppFolder UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInplaceWebApp UP-TO-DATE
:appRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*** What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appRun'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed**

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':appRun'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:306)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed
        at java_util_concurrent_Future$get.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase.launchThread(LauncherBase.groovy:230)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase.launch(LauncherBase.groovy:71)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.Launcher$launch.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.StartBaseTask.action(StartBaseTask.groovy:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServiceProtocol.readMessage(ServiceProtocol.groovy:15)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServiceProtocol$readMessage.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4$_closure9.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy:157)
        at org.akhikhl.gretty.LauncherBase$_launchThread_closure4$_closure9.doCall(LauncherBase.groovy)


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.907 secs
```

Comment: can you provide appRun task definition?

Comment: Im just trying to run the website ,
so first i run the server then when i want to run the website through my local host(server) it doesnt allow me because the only way i connect the website through the server is by the sockets , other than that there isnt a way my website is linked to the server, so i think thats why its giving me the SocketException failed permission.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to bind to a port < 1024 and you don't have superuser privilege.

Comment: im using port 1234, how do you think i should go on about fixing these errors?

Comment: In that case you may be up against a firewall rule.

Comment: i disabled the firewall but it didnt make a difference